# csvkit Permission denied

Tags: osx, python, pip

I am on Mac and installed `csvkit`.  When I run `csvlook`, I get a traceback with the following error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library /Pythong/2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt'
```

Based on the documentation, I also ran the following:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade csvkit
```

Still, no luck. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you check ls -lh /Library /Pythong/2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt and if `-rw-------` you have to change to `-rw-r--r--`. May be [this](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/43187) is your case.

Comment: Yes, this like it is the problem.  It is set to:  `-rw-------`.  I'm not sure where to obtain info on making this change.  Would you mind offering a link or a short description?  Thanks!

Comment: When you are in this directory from command line you can use: chmod 644 * .

Comment: Exactly right. Feel free to put in an answer and I will accept it.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: It is ok, I am glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @taliezin did not post his answer, I'll do it. This fixed the issue for me, in Xubuntu.

You need to make the file /Python/2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt readable not only by root, but also by other users.

So, in a terminal, type each command followed by Enter:

```
sudo -s
cd /Python/2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/
chmod 664 *
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the reason why @colin-maudry's solution works is because this is a known bug specific to `python_dateutil`, as explained in this related SO discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736014/getting-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-importing-pandas-datafra

> This is a known issue with python-dateutil where the permissions aren't set correctly in the pypi package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/1243202. This isn't a problem with pip because pip normalizes permissions, but if you install it differently you might run into problems.

The solution given:

```
  sudo chmod o+r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
```